# How can I add custom fonts to my Kobo ereader?

Tags: fonts, sideloading, customization, kobo

Is it possible to add custom fonts to my Kobo ereader? How can I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, custom fonts are easily added to any ereader of the Kobo family. [An article on MobileRead](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=204363) fully explain how.

> Fonts can be be very easily added to the Kobo family of eReaders. With
>   the Kobo attached to your computer, create a new directory called
>   `fonts` in the root directory of the device (the same location as the
>   `.kobo`, `.adobe-digital-editions` and `Digital Editions` directories.
>
> Once this directory has been created, simply copy entire font families
>   into it.
>
> A font family consists of four files; one each for Regular, Italic,
>   Bold and BoldItalic.
>
> The font should be
>   named the same as the system sees the font, so in the case of Linux
>   Libertine, it's exactly that. You'll have 4 different font file, and
>   you want to name each one in the style `<Font Name>-<Font Weight>`, so
>   for Linux Libertine, you should have 4 files:
>
> `Linux Libertine.ttf` (or `Linux Libertine-Regular.ttf`)
>   `Linux Libertine-Italic.ttf`
>   `Linux Libertine-Bold.ttf`
>   `Linux Libertine-BoldItalic.ttf`
>
> For many fonts, the name can simply be what you'd expect it to be, but
>   for some, the actual font name is different than what seems obvious.
>   And you are correct, all these files go into a folder called "fonts"
>   on your Kobo.

Comment: On Kindle I was disappointed to find out that this only worked for Kindle-bought books, not sideloaded. What is the story here for Kobo?

Answer (score 0):

you have a complete tutorial here for [add a custom font on **Kobo Glo**](http://aedirn.fr/tutoriel-liseuse-kobo-glo-personnaliser-police-ecriture).

Comment: When that link goes dead this answer loses any of its usefulness. Please repeat the actual actions here and provide the link as a reference to detailed information only.