# Installing own font & using it to read ebook

Tags: ebook-readers, fonts, customization

I have been looking for the possibility to install manually a font on an ebook-reader and use that font to display downloaded ebooks. I have not found any clear answer...

The reason is as follows: there are dyslexia-optimized fonts available, reducing the number of errors while reading. The number of printed books using this font however is very limited. 
If it thus would be possible to download a random ebook and configure your ebook-reader in an optimized way (downloaded font, limited amount of text per row, left aligned text), this would be very interesting.

So in fact I have these questions:

1. Is it possible to manually install a font on an ebook-reader?
2. Is it possible to changes the font and text outline in which a ebook is displayed?
3. Does the DRM-type on an ebook file influence the possibilities to change it's appearance (font, text outline) on an ebook-reader?
4. Are there ebook-reader types known to be more flexible in this matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kobo ereaders are known for their font customization capabilities. They have a dozen of preinstalled fonts, and a couple of them aimed exactly to dyslexic readers.
Besides selecting the font, you can also tweak it to your needs with many options for dimensions, spacing, margins, justification and thickness.

You can read a couple of reviews, [here](http://goodereader.com/blog/electronic-readers/hands-on-review-of-the-kobo-glo) and [here](http://goodereader.com/blog/electronic-readers/hands-on-with-the-new-kobo-aura), that explain these features with pictures so you can see if this is what you need.

On Kobo ereaders it is also easy to add custom fonts, [we already have a question on this site that explain how to do it](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/444/136).